# Open file Error permission denied on macOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

hi I use bridging header include a hpp

but always output "Error permission denied"

My Derived Data is relative
I tried to key "chmod -R 777 ./" in Debug-iPhonesimulator

show the code:

```
bool CheckPath()
{
    FILE *pfile = fopen("./__viewtest.txt","w");
    if(pfile){
        fclose(pfile);
        return true;
    }
    printf("Error %s\n",strerror(errno));
    return false;
}
```

it is always output "Error permission denied"

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<iostream>

std::string GetCurrentWorkingDir( void ) {
    char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
    getcwd( buff, FILENAME_MAX );
    std::string current_working_dir(buff);
    return current_working_dir;
}

bool CheckPath()
{
    std::string sPath = GetCurrentWorkingDir();
    sPath += "Users/My/Desktop/WorkSpace/View/DerivedData/View/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/__viewtest.txt";
    FILE *pfile = fopen(sPath.c_str(),"w");
    if(pfile){
        fclose(pfile);
        return true;
    }
    printf(" %s, Path %s\n",strerror(errno), GetCurrentWorkingDir().c_str());
    return false;
}
```